# is there a way to know if a docker container is restarted within another container?

Tags: docker, containers

I need to know if other container has been restarted to run some command in my container. Is there a way to be aware of container restarting within another container?

Comment: Not without being given unrestricted root-level access over the entire host system with no constraints at all.  Why do you need to know this?

Comment: i have redis container , but only very small part of data which should be always updated are important to me ,I don't want to take snapshot or backup from redis. I just want to insert these data as soon as the redis container is restarted, the other data are not important to be lost, so I was just thinking to run my command from other container to add these data to redis

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give any specifics so I assume both containers are running on the same host. In this case a simple solution is to get the restart event from the docker
daemon running on the host and then send a signal to the other container. [`docker events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) can easily do that

Run on the host using, for example, the `docker-compose` service name to filter the events notified for the restarting container:

```
docker events | \
grep --line-buffered 'container restart.*com.docker.compose.service=<compose_service_name>' | \
while read ; do docker kill --signal=SIGUSR1 my_ubuntu ; done
```

The `docker kill --signal=SIGUSR1 my_ubuntu` send the `USR1` signal to the other container where the command needs to be run. To test it, run ubuntu with a `sigtrap` for `USR1`:

```
docker run --rm --name my_ubuntu -it ubuntu /bin/bash \
-c "trap 'echo signal received' USR1; \
while :; do echo loop; sleep 10 & wait ${!}; done;"
```

Now restart the container and the signal handler will execute `echo` inside the other container. It can be replaced with the real command.

The docker events are part of the Docker REST API (see [Monitor Docker's events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/SystemEvents)) so if the other container can connect to the docker daemon running on host, it can get the restart notification directly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this scenario will usually occur if you've mounted /var/docker.sock file in container's file system. You can create, run and check all the events like @b0husb mentioned in his answer with a curl command. You can, therefore, monitor it to check the source of container's creation command.